# CORS policy making problems even after all headers and origins are allowed

Tags: c#, .net-core, cors, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I have a dotnetcoreapp2.1 in which I am using SignalR. I have enabled all origins for testing and all headers but I am getting the following errors:

> ..has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request
>   doesn't pass access control check: The value of the
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the
>   wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The
>   credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is
>   controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

I am used the following configuration:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("MyCORSPolicy", builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                       .AllowAnyMethod()
                       .AllowCredentials() // DisallowCredentials doesn't work either
                       .AllowAnyHeader();
            }));

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

            services.AddSignalR();

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {

            app.UseCors("MyCORSPolicy");

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseMvc();

            app.UseSignalR(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapHub<VehiclesHub>("/vehiclesHub");
            });

            app.UseWebSockets();

        }
```

Now the problem here is that i get this error when I try to access this Hub from react web app. But if I try it from React native I get

> Failed to start the transport 'websockets' null

I have even used on my HUB or other controllers

```
[EnableCors("MyCORSPolicy")]
```

This problem was occurring on all web api 2 controllers, but now I am failing with SignalR hub only. Other api endpoints are working fine.

EDIT:

My dotnetcore2.2 app is hosted on IIS server.

Comment: Does AllowAnyOrigin() always cause the system to set the value of the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header to the `*` wildcard? You probably only want to be allowing credentialed requests just from a discrete set of known/allowed sites.

Comment: @sideshowbarker I have also tried to use DisallowCredentials and leaving both options not set as well. Doesn't work.

Comment: With CORS, the recommended way to handle credentialed requests on the server side is to have some logic that checks the value of the Origin request header against a set of known/allowed origins, and then only sends back the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header if the origin is in that allowed set. And in that case, the server sends by the actual origin value (from the Origin request header) as the value of the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header (rather than sending back the wildcard value).

Comment: @sideshowbarker what should it return if its going to be used from a react native mobile app?

Comment: You can’t prevent that `The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'` error just by making server-side changes. The cause of that error is that there’s some frontend JavaScript code that’s setting the credentials mode to ‘include’, and browsers block frontend JavaScript code from accessing any response that has an Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header with the `*` wildcard and with an Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header whose value is ‘true’.

Comment: I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aspnet/signalr so not custom request is made here. What their documentation is telling me, I am using that.

Comment: As far as what the server should return: If you don’t actually want the server to support credentialed requests, then it’s fine to just have it return the wildcard. But in that case of course you want to also make sure you’re not having any frontend JavaScript code try to add credentials to a request. It’s also fine to always have the server return the value of the Origin header. But if you do that, and you also do actually want to allow credentials to be included, then as explained in previous comments, it’s recommended that only send back the Access-Control-Allow-Origin to allowed origins.

Comment: app.UseWebSockets() can accept WebSocketOptions, but if WebSocketOptions.AllowedOrigins are not specified or WebSocketOptions param is not specified, default value kicks in and all origins are allowed, so that is not the problem.

Comment: Can you suggest me anything to try?

Comment: @Waleed You need to explicitly specify the allowed origins using `.WithOrigins("https://example.com")`.

Comment: @Brennan what will be origin for android devices? I am using this in a react-native app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems that in my case origin is not an issue since users will be accessing data using their credentials. I researched more that CORS is for browsers mostly where users can be injected and harmed with a script on cross origin.

So solution that I found on my Github post was to create a custom middleware which solves this problem. Since I had no control on withCredentials used inside ASP.NET Core Signalr, so returning same origin using a middleware is the best option here:

```
public class CorsOverride
{
  private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

  public CorsOverride(RequestDelegate next)
  {
    _next = next;
  }

  public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
  {
    const string allowOriginHeaderName = "Access-Control-Allow-Origin";
    if (httpContext.Response.Headers.ContainsKey(allowOriginHeaderName))
    {
      httpContext.Response.Headers.Remove(allowOriginHeaderName);
    }

    httpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    httpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");

    if (httpContext.Request.Headers["Access-Control-Request-Method"].Count > 0)
    {
      foreach (var header in httpContext.Request.Headers["Access-Control-Request-Method"])
      {
        httpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", header);
      }
    }
    else
    {
      httpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", httpContext.Request.Method);
    }

    foreach (var origin in httpContext.Request.Headers.Where(h => h.Key == "Origin"))
    {
      httpContext.Response.Headers.Add(allowOriginHeaderName, origin.Value);
    }

    if (httpContext.Request.Method == "OPTIONS")
    {
      httpContext.Response.StatusCode = 200;
      await httpContext.Response.WriteAsync("");
    }
    else
    {
      await _next.Invoke(httpContext);
    }
  }
}
```

[My article for CORS handling](http://www.techcuriosity.net/asp-net-core-2-cross-origin-requests-cors-handling/)

If anybody has any objection with this type of fix, please commend below.